# How can record all ip address visited from my pc with tcpdump?

Tags: tcpdump

I want to record all ip address requested from my local pc ,how can record all ip address with tcpdump?

Comment: why do you want to use tcpdump?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to record the IP addresses then it would be easier to do this with iptables & logging...

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp -m state --state NEW  -j LOG \
  --log-level 1 --log-prefix "New Connection "
```

If you really want to use tcpdump, something like....

```
tcpdump "tcp[tcpflags] & tcp-syn != 0"
```